# Provide Ionic 5 Privay/Permission in capactor config

Tags: angular, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

Is there a possibility of defining the Privacy string, which is needed to access the camera on the device via the capacitor config or any other config?

```
{
      "appId": "at.your.identifier",
      "appName": "appName",
      "plugins": {
        "SplashScreen": {
          "launchShowDuration": 2000,
          "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP"
        },
        "Keyboard": {
          "resize": "body",
          "style": "dark"
        }
      }
    }
```

appName and appId e.g are used by the native environemts, such as xCode and Android Studio. But I cant see the options of defining more things than that.

Why is it useful? Because i have to write these and many other configs anytime I have to rebuild the app from scratch.

Comment: For Android add permissions on `AndroidManifest.xml`. and for IOS you have to add usage String inside `info.plist`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I dont want to add them on every new build, this should be done within the capacitor config or equivalent.

Comment: these are one time permissions. you don't have to add them in every build.